# Odd ratios and 95% confidence intervals from logistic regression on data imputed with MICE

Tags: r, logistic-regression, missing-data, glm, r-mice

I have data with missing values which I imputed using the MICE package.

```
impData <- mice(analysis_set,m=5,maxit=50,meth='pmm',seed=500)
```

Now I need to run logistic regression analysis:

```
modelFit1 <- with(data = impData, 
exp = glm(formula = Outcome ~ inputVar1 + inputVar2 + inputVar3, 
family = binomial(link = "logit")))
```

I can get a pooled analysis using:

```
pool(modelFit1)
```

And more info using:

```
summary(pool(modelFit1))
```

The last command shows the estimates, SE, t, df, Pr(>|t|), lo 95, hi 95, nmis, fmi and lambda.

My question is: is there an easy way to obtain the ORs and 95% CI from the pooled analysis?

I used to do that on a dataset using:

```
exp(cbind(OR = coef(mylogit), confint(mylogit)))
```

where mylogit is the glm() for a dataset. Is there an equivalent to that for the pooled analysis?

Comment: The summary returns a matrix: just pull out the relevant columns and exponentiate

Comment: Thanks that was helpful! Posted the full answer.

Comment: Maybe this helps simplifying things: https://github.com/pat-s/oddsratio

Answer (score 2):

The pooled object is under the class `mipo` from MICE package.

```
summary(pool(modelFit1), conf.int = TRUE, exponentiate = TRUE)
```

gives both Odds Ratio (estimate) and corresponding CIs.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @user20650

```
summaryPool <- summary(pool(modelFit1))
exp(cbind(summaryPoolM2[,1],summaryPoolM2[,6],summaryPoolM2[,7]))
```

Column 1 is the estimates, 6 and 7 are the ln(95% confidence intervals). Exponentiating these values gives the ORs and 95% CIs.

Comment: you could avoid a bit of typing by using `exp(summaryPoolM2[, c("est", "lo 95", "hi 95")])`

Comment: That's handy. Thanks!